# vb resize image so that it automatically fits

Tags: image, vb6, resize

I am a newbie to VB 6 and I am facing a problem. I have a large picture. I want to place it in a quite smaller form so that it looks nice with the short text.

However when I add the picture in the picture box, the picture is added from top-left and the right and bottom parts are cut off. Sometimes I also need to re-size the picture box. So I would like to know how to make the image fit in the picture box automatically and get re-sized automatically whenever I re-size the picture box. I have searched for help but could not find any help in this context.
I have also tried making the AutoSize and AutoRedraw options 'true' but still it is't working.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming this *is* a VB6 question and not VB.NET as you've tagged it...

If you just want to display a picture and don't require any of the other properties, methods and events associated with a `PictureBox,` you can use an `Image` control and set its `Stretch` property to `True.`

If you *do* need it to be a `PictureBox,` you can do it by adding a second, hidden, AutoSizing `PictureBox` which is set to the desired picture then use code like this to draw it rescaled onto the visible `PictureBox.`

```
pbxShown.PaintPicture pbxHidden.Picture, _
        0, 0, pbxShown.ScaleWidth, pbxShown.ScaleHeight, _
        0, 0, pbxHidden.ScaleWidth, pbxHidden.ScaleHeight, _
        vbSrcCopy
```

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty: Eh? It's a standard component in the VB6 toolbox. You add it the same way you add any other control...

Comment: Hey I  understood it. Its fantastic ... +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Set AutoSize Property to True of Picture Box Property

Answer (score 0):

Code to automatically stretch loaded picture in picture box,

```
Private Sub AutoSizeToPicture(Picture1 As PictureBox)
    Picture1.ScaleMode = 3
    Picture1.AutoRedraw = True
    Picture1.PaintPicture Picture1.Picture, _
    0, 0, Picture1.ScaleWidth, Picture1.ScaleHeight, _
    0, 0, Picture1.Picture.Width / 26.46, _
    Picture1.Picture.Height / 26.46
End Sub
```